# python 3 printing a picross board

Tags: python

Im having trouble with a function on python in which I am required to print a picross board (I am not using a graphic interface). We have to create a board from the specification of the board which is a tuple like this one: `e=(((2,), (3,), (2,), (2, 2), (2,)), ((2,), (1, 2), (2,), (3,), (3,)))`. The board should look like this:

[image]

but I don't know how to insert the tuple values to the columns and rows.
this is my code:

```
t=[[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], [((3,), (2,), (2, 2), (2,)), ((2,), (1, 2), (2,), (0,))]]

j=0

for i in t[0]:

    if j == 4:

        print(" "*len(t[1][0])+"|")
        j=0
    if i==[0]:    
        print ("[ ? ]", end="")
        j +=1
    elif i==[1]:
        print("[ . ]", end="")
        j+=1
    else:
        print("[ X ]", end="")
        j+=1

print(" "*len(t[1][0])+"|")
```

it prints everything right except for the tuple numbers.

it returns this:

```
[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ]    |

[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ]    |

[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ]    |

[ ? ][ ? ][ ? ][ ? ]    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt at it:

```
t = [[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]],
     [((3,), (2,), (2, 2), (2,)),
      ((2,), (1, 2), (2,), (0,))]]

board_size = len(t[1][0])
cells = t[0]
hnums = t[1][0] # These are the horizontal numbers
vnums = t[1][1] # These are the vertical numbers

# Here I'm building new lists using list comprehension.
# I've noticed that some of the numbers are missing the second element.
# For example here ((2,), (1, 2), (2,), (0,)), only the second element (1, 2) has two members. So I had to make sure this condition is taken care of by adding this x[1] if len(x) > 1 which means only take the second element if the length of the total tuple is more than 1.
# If you haven't seen list comperhension before, you need to look them up because they are a huge topic.
# at the end of these lines we will have something like this
# h1 = [' ', ' ', 2, ' ']
# h2 = [3, 2, 2, 2]

h1 = [x[1] if len(x) > 1 else " " for x in hnums]
h2 = [x[0] for x in hnums]
v1 = [x[1] if len(x) > 1 else " " for x in vnums]
v2 = [x[0] for x in vnums]

# Here I'm building the two horizontal lines
# heading_string will look like this '  {}    {}    {}    {}  ' because the board size is 4. Notice that this will work with other sizes if you changed the t variable.
heading_string = "  {}  " * board_size
# Here I'm just calling the format function and passing in the h1 variable.
# The * will unpack the list.
# The end result will be '  {}    {}    {}    {}  '.format(' ', ' ', 2, ' ')
# So each parameter of the format function will be replaced with the {} placeholder
print(heading_string.format(*h1)) 
print(heading_string.format(*h2))

# Here I'm just defining a function to take care of the logic of the cell text
def cell_text(c):
    if c == [0]:
        return "?"
    elif c == [1]:
        return "."
    else:
        return "X"

row = [] # a row list that will represent the each row of cells
# for loop using enumerate and starting from 1. So i will equal to 1 in the first loop
for i, cell in enumerate(cells, 1):
    row.append(cell_text(cell)) # appending cells to the row list

    # if i in the current loop is 4, 8, 12, 16 this condition will be true and we need to break the row to create a new one for the next row 
    if i % board_size == 0:
        row_string = "[ {} ]" * board_size # Same thing as heading_string
        # Here I'm building the vertical numbers string
        # The numbers are stored in v1 and v2
        # and they both have 4 members indexed 0, 1, 2, 3
        # That's why I'm subtracting 1 from i because i starts from 1 not from 0 because of enumerate(cells, 1).
        # This will work fine for the first four elements 
        # but in the fifth loop, i = 4 and we actually need v1[0]
        # and that's why I'm dividing by the board size to get the correct index
        vnum_string = " " + str(v2[(i-1) // board_size]) + " " \
                          + str(v1[(i-1) // board_size]) + " |"
        print(row_string.format(*row) + vnum_string) # Same as before except that I'm adding the vertical numbers string
        row = [] # Reset the row list
```

Comment: It is returning error on line 33 saying that list indices must be integers, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Yeah it must be the division operator "/" I should have changed it to integer division "//". I'll update the answer.

Comment: Would you mind adding some comments to let me know what each thing does?

Comment: Here you go :) to learn more about list comprehension check some youtube videos on the subject. Like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7EYKuZJfdA

Comment: it´s just that i changed my intern representation of a board and it now looks like this but i dont know how to print it again! I´m sorry but i´m in a hurry to finish this print so i can move on with the rest. t=[(((2,), (3,), (2,), (2, 2), (2,)), ((2,), (1, 2), (2,), (3,), (3,))), [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]
this is the new representation. plus the lines are t[0][0] and the columns are t[0][1]. other thing, for example on t[0][1][1] the tuple is (1, 2,) and when you print it it the numbers are in the wrong order. Can you help me?